# How to show toast message from background thread

Tags: java, android

Consider the following code. In `Service.onStart()` method i have created and started a thread that should show Toast message but it is not working!

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";  
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;    
    }       

    @Override   
    public void onCreate()
    {   
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }  
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {   
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }   
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
      Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      DBIteratorThread dbThread=new DBIteratorThread();
      dbThread.myService=this;
      Thread t1 = new Thread(dbThread);
           t1.start();
    }

}
class DBIteratorThread  implements Runnable
{

    MyService myService;

    public void run()
    {
    //  Toast.makeText(myService, "Thread is Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
}
```

Comment: This should work for you also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134013/android-how-can-i-show-a-toast-from-a-thread-running-in-a-remote-service

Answer (score 28):

Do UI stuffs in main/UI thread. Try this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your UI code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

I have written a class for showing `Toasts` from background processes. Can be used everywhere, e.g. in an `AsyncTask`. You only have to create an instance of this class like

```
ToastHandler mToastHandler = new ToastHandler(yourContext);
```

and then call `showToast()` with your text or resource id and the `Toast's` duration like you normally would with `makeToast()`.

Here is the code or the direct download [**link**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/223622/ToastHandler.java):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A class for showing a <code>Toast</code> from background processes using a
 * <code>Handler</code>.
 * 
 * @author kaolick
 */
public class ToastHandler
{
    // General attributes
    private Context mContext;
    private Handler mHandler;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     * 
     * @param _context
     *            The <code>Context</code> for showing the <code>Toast</code>
     */
    public ToastHandler(Context _context)
    {
    this.mContext = _context;
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    /**
     * Runs the <code>Runnable</code> in a separate <code>Thread</code>.
     * 
     * @param _runnable
     *            The <code>Runnable</code> containing the <code>Toast</code>
     */
    private void runRunnable(final Runnable _runnable)
    {
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        mHandler.post(_runnable);
        }
    };

    thread.start();
    thread.interrupt();
    thread = null;
    }

    /**
     * Shows a <code>Toast</code> using a <code>Handler</code>. Can be used in
     * background processes.
     * 
     * @param _resID
     *            The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be
     *            formatted text.
     * @param _duration
     *            How long to display the message. Only use LENGTH_LONG or
     *            LENGTH_SHORT from <code>Toast</code>.
     */
    public void showToast(final int _resID, final int _duration)
    {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
        // Get the text for the given resource ID
        String text = mContext.getResources().getString(_resID);

        Toast.makeText(mContext, text, _duration).show();
        }
    };

    runRunnable(runnable);
    }

    /**
     * Shows a <code>Toast</code> using a <code>Handler</code>. Can be used in
     * background processes.
     * 
     * @param _text
     *            The text to show. Can be formatted text.
     * @param _duration
     *            How long to display the message. Only use LENGTH_LONG or
     *            LENGTH_SHORT from <code>Toast</code>.
     */
    public void showToast(final CharSequence _text, final int _duration)
    {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, _text, _duration).show();
        }
    };

    runRunnable(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "thread.interrupt()" and "thread = null" in runRunnable()? Setting thread to null is redundant since that variable  disappears when the function returns anyway.

Comment: I'm no `thread` expert. I just wanted to avoid possible problems or side effects. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the getApplicationContext() method to get the context with which to show the Toast.

See [getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext) for some nice discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `this` with `getBaseContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a Toast on a thread that is not the activity's ui thread.

you can only run it somewhere else if you use `runOnUiThread` method so that it runs on the ui thread

Look at this question
[[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread)

Answer (score 0):

We use handler for this purpose because it is easy... :)

Steps:

1. declare a handler in the main activity (onCreate)
2. a class which is to be run in the background in that create a parameterized constructor . Taking the Context a perimeter .
3. now create a thread from the main activity and pass the Context of that activity.
4. now Post to the handler from that another thread (from whichever thread u want to send)
5. now use this context in the Toast, instead of using getApplicationContext()

It runs well.

```
mhandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Run ends",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace word `this` with `getApplicationContext()` The message will then appear

```
Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**the correct :**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```