# Send a toast from a thread within a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, toast

I'm trying to send a toast notification of an error in a thread. The thread is started in a service that is called from the main thread. I've tried several things with `View.post` and some weird handler stuff, but nothing seems to work. An excerpt of the thread is as follows:

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            boolean bol = true;

            while (bol)
            {

                try 
                {
                    //Some socket code...
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                 //Where I want the toast code.
                } 
            }

        }
    }).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try following inside the thread in the service:

```
Handler h = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
     // Although you need to pass an appropriate context
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Taken from answer given by @Alex Gitelman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134095/1306419) on [Android: How can i show a toast from a thread running in a remote service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134013/android-how-can-i-show-a-toast-from-a-thread-running-in-a-remote-service) . This might help somebody as it helped me.

Comment: I get "  'Handler' is abstract; cannot be instantiated" error in android studio 2.2.2. Edit: thats because I used the wrong handler. Use android.os.Handler;

Comment: That's the right answer! every body else is saying about runOnUiThread

Answer (score 2):

Toast can be shown only from UI Thread (Main Thread). To show Toast from some other threads you have to use `Handler`.

[Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is it any different because I'm within a service and not the main activity?

Comment: Won't there be a static problem though? If I define a handler as an instance object then I'm not going to be able to call it from the thread since the thread is static.

Comment: I never put it as static, I defined it exactly as above. Is there another way to define a thread?

Comment: From your code it seems this thread can't be stopped. Put the thread class as a innerclass of service. Then start it from onStartCommand().. Use handler to show toast.. then kill thread..

Comment: How do I make it an innerclass of service exactly? I'm not very good with the service/thread concepts yet...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use a `Handler`, and bind you `Activity` to your `Service`

Once the `Handler` is set, here is what you should do,

```
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyActivity.TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(MyActivity.TOAST_MSG, "Toast message");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    try {
        myActivityMessenger.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        if (D) Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send() the toast message back to the UI.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`myActivityMessenger` is set with the `Handler` of your `MyActivity` and sent to the `Service` when you bind `MyActivity` to it.

However displaying a `Toast` with a `Service` as context should work (but it's not the best way), so maybe it's because you try to make it from a new Thread. What is your code for making the `Toast` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        _dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LatestNewsActivity.this, "NO Internet Connection Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }   
    }.start();
```

Comment: If this is not an innerclass of something like Activity, then you have to provide a context.runOnUiThread right?