# Getting error while mailing large image(>500 KB) using Java Mail API in Android

Tags: java, android, service, jakarta-mail, android-context

I am building an Android app through which i want to instantly mail the photos taken from device camera.
I want this to be done in Background, so i used JAVA Mail API, and I am starting a service to mail the images.

Till now my code is working fine with images < 50 KB , but it is throwing weird error when I am trying to mail image >= 500 KB .
for now i am using hardcoded values for files and username, password.

### Code of my background Service :-

```
public class BgMailer extends Service{

private ArrayList<String>Recievers ;
private String msg,sub;
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service created",5000).show();


    super.onCreate();

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Toast.makeText(this, DataHolder., duration)
    //sendMail();
      Notification note = new Notification( 0, null, System.currentTimeMillis() );
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground( 42, note );

    Recievers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("recievers");
    sub = intent.getStringExtra("sub");
    msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");

    sendMail(Recievers, sub, msg);
//  stopForeground(true);

    this.stopSelf();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service destroyed",5000).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public  void sendMail(ArrayList<String>recvr,String sub,String msg){
     Mail m = new Mail("r4jiv007@gmail.com", "<password>");

     String [] address = new String[recvr.size()];
        address = recvr.toArray(address);
        m.set_to(address);
        m.set_from("r4jiv007@gmail.com");
        m.set_subject(sub);
        m.setBody(msg);

        try {
             m.addAttachment("/sdcard/1.jpg");
           //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/1.txt");
     //     m.addAttachment("/sdcard/bday.jpg");
          if(m.send()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        } 
}

}
```

---

Error values in LogCat :-

```
10-20 01:34:13.690: W/ActivityManager(134): Timeout executing service: 
ServiceRecord{40ae01d0 my.com.cnm/.BgMailer}
10-20 01:34:13.800: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 1845 SIG: 3
10-20 01:34:13.800: I/dalvikvm(1845): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-20 01:34:13.820: I/dalvikvm(1845): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-20 01:34:13.830: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 134 SIG: 3
10-20 01:34:13.830: I/dalvikvm(134): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-20 01:34:13.870: I/dalvikvm(134): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-20 01:34:13.870: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 235 SIG: 3
10-20 01:34:13.870: I/dalvikvm(235): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-20 01:34:13.880: I/dalvikvm(235): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-20 01:34:13.880: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 239 SIG: 3
10-20 01:34:13.880: I/dalvikvm(239): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-20 01:34:13.900: I/dalvikvm(239): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-20 01:34:13.900: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 208 SIG: 3
10-20 01:34:13.900: I/dalvikvm(208): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-20 01:34:13.900: I/dalvikvm(208): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-20 01:34:14.481: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1427K, 32% free 9016K/13191K, external 607K/1119K, paused 8ms+16ms
10-20 01:34:14.821: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 379K, 32% free 9072K/13191K, external 607K/1119K, paused 171ms
10-20 01:34:15.432: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 1657 SIG: 3
10-20 01:34:15.432: I/dalvikvm(1657): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-20 01:34:15.432: I/dalvikvm(1657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): ANR in my.com.cnm:Bgmailer time=4035592
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): Reason: Executing service my.com.cnm/.BgMailer
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): Load: 3.78 / 3.97 / 3.79
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): CPU usage from 13492ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   1.4% 230/com.htc.android.htcime: 1.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 746 minor 3 major
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   4% 1845/my.com.cnm:Bgmailer: 3.7% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 63 minor
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   2.2% 239/android.process.acore: 2.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   1.5% 272/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   1.2% 134/system_server: 0.7% user + 0.5% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0.8% 81/akmd: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0.6% 1657/my.com.cnm: 0.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 4 minor
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0.5% 424/com.android.htccontacts: 0.5% user + 0% kernel / faults: 54 minor
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0.1% 208/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 271/dhd_watchdog: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 5/events/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 14/kondemand/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 64/kgsl-3d0/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 83/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 291/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 552/com.ebuddy.android.xms: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0% 753/com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   0.1% 848/com.google.android.apps.maps:LocationFriendService: 0% user + 0% kernel + 0%         iowait
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): 19% TOTAL: 16% user + 2.3% kernel + 0.3% iowait + 0.1% softirq
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): CPU usage from 1133ms to 1688ms later:
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   8.9% 134/system_server: 0% user + 8.9% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):     5.3% 157/ActivityManager: 0% user + 5.3% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):     1.7% 140/SurfaceFlinger: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   1.7% 81/akmd: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):     3.5% 1722/akmd: 3.5% user + 0% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134):   1.2% 1657/my.com.cnm: 1.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
10-20 01:34:15.442: E/ActivityManager(134): 14% TOTAL: 5.3% user + 8.9% kernel
10-20 01:34:15.452: I/Process(134): Sending signal. PID: 1845 SIG: 9
10-20 01:34:15.452: I/ActivityManager(134): Skipping background ANR: my.com.cnm:Bgmailer time=4035592
10-20 01:34:15.462: I/ActivityManager(134): Process my.com.cnm:Bgmailer (pid 1845) has died.
```

is there any thing related to priority or service here, i even tried to run my service as a foreground application , but of no use .. and i am not able to figure out how to solve this.
i would appreciate any help in this !!

thanks :)

well thanks for the suggestion for this problem , i just created a thread and mailed the image through it and it was successful .. but i want to show a toast when the mailing process completed successfully but i am getting following error :-

```
 E/MailApp(2131): Could not send email
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
at my.com.cnm.BgMailer.sendMail(BgMailer.java:86)
at my.com.cnm.BgMailer$1.run(BgMailer.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

Comment: Doesn't that say that you have stack traces in traces.txt, might be good to look there.

Comment: what is the error you get? is it crashing? do you see any exception in logcat..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar i have mentioned my logcat values please go through that

Comment: are you getting any error in the app UI? 

please also check my answer and try to put your send email code in separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since service also run in process main thread you might try to create separate thread in the service to send the email..

following is from the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work.

check out the accepted answer in the following post to show the Toast from background thread:

[Android: How can i show a toast from a thread running in a remote service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134013/android-how-can-i-show-a-toast-from-a-thread-running-in-a-remote-service)

Comment: i am creating service in separate process by mentioning that in the manifest file.
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BgMailer"
            android:process=":Bgmailer"/>
so its is running as separate process and i am sure about that

Comment: how are you starting your service?

Comment: Intent bgmail = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BgMailer.class);
      bgmail.putStringArrayListExtra("recievers", DataHolder.Email_list);
      bgmail.putExtra("sub", DataHolder.SUB);
      bgmail.putExtra("msg", DataHolder.MSG);
      startService(bgmail);

Comment: I could see following two lines in the error code..
10-20 01:34:15.452: I/ActivityManager(134): Skipping background ANR: my.com.cnm:Bgmailer time=4035592
10-20 01:34:15.462: I/ActivityManager(134): Process my.com.cnm:Bgmailer (pid 1845) has died.

can you please try once with a thread in the service just to see if this is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an `ANR` because it's taking so long, maybe if you put the sending code in an `AsyncTask` so it runs on a background thread it wont be detected as an `ANR`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: is it necessary to be AsyncTask or should i create a thread for that as mentioned in this page :-
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html

Comment: You should do it in an `AsyncTask` and when it's complete, you could use the `onPostExecute()` to give a Toast that the mail has been successfully sent, for instance.