# Android create new thread in service class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class, service

I created a service class and now I'am trying to run a new thread in this class. Service is started in my `MainActivity` and this works well. The first `Toast.Message` in the `onCreate()` section shows up, but the message in my thread `runa()` doesn't come up. Thought that it should work with a new `Runnable()`.

```
public class My Service extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    Thread readthread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //is shown

        readthread = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { try {
            runa();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } } });

        readthread.start(); 

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    }
    public void runa() throws Exception{

        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //doesn't show up

    }
}
```

Would be nice if anyone could help me:)

Comment: do you get any exceptions? I guess the `Thread` is executed on a background `Thread` from where you can not show a toast.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu your comment is the answser to his question. Move it as answer, please

Comment: ok thank you, is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Thread` that you are creating, will not be executed on the `MainThread`, thus you can not show a `Toast` from it. To display a `Toast` from a background `Thread` you will have to use a `Handler`, and use that `Handler` to display the `Toast`.

```
private MyService extends Service {
    Handler mHandler=new Handler();
    //...

    public void runa() throws Exception{
        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This would be the solution for your exact problem, although I don't consider it a good 'architecture' or practice as I don't know exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show Toasts from non-UI threads. Your Service is running on the main thread but you are running your `runa()` method in a background thread. You have to use a handler and ask it to display the toast on the UI thread. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134095/1369222) to find out how this is done.

Comment: ok this looks good, but I'am not sure how to pass the context

Comment: the `Service` runs on the `MainThread`. `IntentService`runs on a background thread.

Comment: Service runs on the [Main Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) by default so you should create a seperate Thread to make it run in background.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu It was a typo. Fixed it now.

Comment: @user2295158 Service is a Context. Simply store a reference to it in your onCreate() using context = this and pass it in later when you need it.

Comment: I'd make context a WeakReference, though.

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to update the UI from a Thread, is using a handler or UIThread**

**Try this code:** and not forget to put the service into the `Manifest` file first.

```
class CapturingSerivce extends Service {
 Handler mHandler=new Handler();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

 public void runa() throws Exception{
        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

            }
        });
    }    


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }
}
```