# show toast msg from a non-activity class which is called by a service class

Tags: android, service, toast

I have a service class MyService and its method MyMethod in which Class B(non activity) is instantiated and class B's method is called. the method displays a toast msg

```
public class MyService extends Service  {

  public void MyMethod() {
 B b=new B();
 b.methodOfB();
}

 Class B
 {
void methodOfB(){
 Toast(.....);
 }
 }
```

Please tell how to make this toast msg work.

Comment: for the toast you need a Context. Service is a Context same as Activity.

Comment: pass the context to methodofB(Context context)

Comment: Try `Toast.makeText(MyService.this.getApplicationConext(), "My Text", Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show()`.

Comment: see this question and answer it will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134013/android-how-can-i-show-a-toast-from-a-thread-running-in-a-remote-service

Answer (score 0):

You can extends MyService (Parent class) to its B class (Child class) and then you can use Toast easily. Like this :

```
public class MyService extends Service  {

  public void MyMethod() {
 B b=new B();
 b.methodOfB();
}

 Class B extends MyService
 {
void methodOfB(){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Your message here...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

send the context of your activity to non activity like

```
BMethod=new BMethod(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Service` is a subclass of `Context`. Hence, we can pass it to the class `B` as:

```
public class MyService extends Service  {

 public void MyMethod() {
    B b=new B(this);
    b.methodOfB();
}
```

And class B has a `Context` reference as:

```
 class B
 {
    private Context context;

    public B(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void methodOfB(){

        //now create the toast message
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
```